# C++ Finding Specific characters in a string

Tags: c++

Writing a program that asks the user to insert a word. The word gets stored in a string, then the user is asked to insert the position of a character in the word they want displayed. IE. User inputs Peanuts, User then inputs 4, Output is N

Comment: Go ahead and do that, and come back to us when you have an actual question.

Comment: using present tense is quite innovative for a do my homework question. You are writing this question while writing and running the code? Sounds like you are on the right track....

Comment: You should define whether the index is 1-based or 0-based.  If the index is 1-based, you'll have to subtract 1 before using the number as an index into an `std::string` or character array.

Comment: Sorry really new to coding in general @ThomasMatthews so I don't quite understand the index, is that something I can easy see? I ran into that exact problem where I must be 1 based and using the 0 made my output incorrect by 1 added character.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s = "thisisastring";

    int position = 0;

    cin>>position;

    cout<<s.at(position);

    return 0;
}
```

If you enter 4 it will output 'i' because the starter index of the string is 0.. if you want to output the 4^ character you need to to use `cout<<s.at(position-1);`

if you enter '0' or a number over than `string.lenght()` this code generate an error, if to want to prevent this issue you have to run this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s = "thisisastring";

    int position = 0;

    do{
        cin>>position;

    }while(position <=0 || position > s.length());

    cout<<s.at(position);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, strings have been very confusing for me and this was a great help!